# How to translate nested if-else in python list comprehension

Tags: python, list, if-statement, list-comprehension

I am trying to convert the "conventional" nested if-else to list comprehension in python but I was not able to accomplish it.

```
def functst(a, list_a, b, list_b):
    list_result = []
    for i in range(len(list_a)):
        if a != 0:
            if list_a[i] <= a:
                list_result.insert(i, 1)
            else:
                list_result.insert(i, a/list_a[i] * (1 - list_b[i]))
        elif list_a[i] <= b:
             list_result.insert(i,1)
        else:
            list_result.insert(i, b/list_a[i] * (1-list_b[i]))
    return list_result
```

I would like to convert it to list comprehension using nested if-else. Any inputs?

Comment: example input and output will be more helpful for validation

Comment: Similarly, can you be more clear about what exactly `functst()` is supposed to *do*, exactly? There might even be a way to do it more concisely while writing the code from scratch

Comment: plus writing this whole code as list comprehension is bad idea

Comment: don't do it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At each iteration, you're evaluating a function of 2 constants (`a`, `b`) and two variables (the contents of `list_a` and `list_b`). My recommendation would be to move the logic into a helper function which takes in these 4 parameters.

```
def helper(a, A, b, B):
    if a != 0:
        if A <= a:
            return 1
        else:
            return a/A*(1-B)
    elif A <=b:
        return 1
    else:
        return b/A*(1-B)
```

Now you can call `helper` inside of a list comprehension using `zip`:

```
list_result = [helper(a,A_val,b,B_val) for A_val, B_val in zip(list_a, list_b)]
```

Also as a side note, if you're going to use your original function you should be using `append` instead of `insert`. After that change, your original method is just as pythonic as a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Ugly, but it does the job:

```py
list_result = [
  (
    1
    if list_a[i] <= a else
    a/list_a[i] * (1 - list_b[i])
  )
  if a != 0 else
  (
    1
    if list_a[i] <= b else
    b/list_a[i] * (1-list_b[i])
  )
  for i in xrange(len(list_a))
]
```

Personally, I'm against such a complex logic; albeit your solution may appear non-Pythonic, it's easier to comprehend.

If you are interested in details, these were my steps:

1. Deal with outer `if`:

```py
list_result = [
  (first condition)
  if a != 0 else
  (second condition)
  (for i in something, or for element in set, or... don't care yet)
]
```

2. Build the first nested `if`:

```py
list_result = [
  (
    1
    if list_a[i] <= a else
    a/list_a[i] * (1 - list_b[i])
  )
  if a != 0 else
  (second condition)
  (still skipping the iteration part, will return later to it)
]
```

3. Build the second nested `if` in the same fashion.
4. Finally, construct the iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you'd want to do this, but maybe

```py
if a:
  return [1 if list_a[i] <= a else (a / list_a[i] * (1 - list_b[i]))
          for i in range(len(list_a))]
else:
  return [1 if list_a[i] <= b else (b / list_a[i] * (1 - list_b[i]))
          for i in range(len(list_a))]
```

You could make it a one-liner with `return [<first list>] if a else [<second list>]`
or possibly a single comprehension with nesting:

```py
[(... if ... <= a else ...) if a
 else (... if ... <= b else ...)
 for i in range(...)]
```

But really, why do that?